# Ef Core 7, how to get one latest message per customer with take and skip

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have below customer and customer message model. I want to get top n customers with latest messages and have only the latest message per customer included.

I am using EfCore 7 on Postgres and my database has around a million customers and each customer might have a around 10 to 100 messages.

```cs
public class Customer 
{
    public long Id{ get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerMessage>? CustomerMessages { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMessage
{
    public long Id{ get; set;}
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc{ get; set;}
}
```

Customer Message Table:

| CustomerId | Message | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | Test2 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | Test3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | Test4 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | Test5 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | Test6 | 2022-01-03 |
| 3 | Test7 | 2022-01-03 |

Customer Table:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Joe |
| 3 | Jim |

Result with `take=2`, `skip=0`. result is based on latest messages received:

`[
{
"Id":2,
"Name":"Joe",
"CustomerMessages":[{
"Message":"Test5"}]},

{
"Id:3,
"Name":"Jim",
"CustomerMessages":[{
"Message":"Test7"}]}]`

Please suggest
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var n = 10;
var query = context.Customers
    .Include(c => c.CustomerMessages.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedOnUtc).Take(1))
    .Take(n)
    .ToList();
```

Or via custom projection, which is closer to your JSON

```cs
var n = 10;
var query = context.Customers
    .Take(n)
    .Select(c => new 
    {
        c.Id,
        Name = c.FirstName,
        CustomerMessages = c.CustomerMessages
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedOnUtc)
            .Take(1)
            .Select(m => new { m.Message })
            .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**, based on updated requirements

```cs
var n = 10;

var joinQuery = 
    from c in context.Customers
    from m in c.CustomerMessages
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedOnUtc)
        .Take(1)
    orderby m.CreatedOnUtc descending
    select new 
    {
        Customer = c, 
        Message = new { m.Message }
    };

var query = joinQuery
    .Take(n)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Customer.Id,
        Name = x.Customer.FirstName,
        CustomerMessage = new { m.Message.Message },
    });
```